# Is there SS4.3 code to show Silvershop featured products on a custom homepage template

Tags: php, silverstripe-4, silvershop

I am trying to create a Silvershop site for myself but the current code suggested to show the featured products on another template page is not working on SS4.3. Is there additional code that I need to add to make the suggested code work in the newer silverstripe 4?

This is the resource I have been using:
https://silverstripe-shop.readthedocs.io/en/stable/en/02_Customisation/01_Recipes/Featured_Products/
I have had to make some tweaks along the way and for most part I have managed to get it working but I am not sure how to tweak this code to make it work.

```
class IndexPageController extends PageController {
}

/**
* Get all products marked as featured that can be purchased.
*/

class IndexPageController extends ProductCategory_Controller   {

   function FeaturedProducts()
   {
       return Product::get()->filter(array(
           'Featured' => 1
           'AllowPurchase' => 1
       ));
   }
}
```

The page shows the error message "currently unable to handle this request."

Comment: I tried variations of other solutions to similar questions but I am still not able to show the newest products on my custom IndexPage.

function FeaturedProducts()
   {
    $ProductCategory = \\silvershop\core\src\Page\ProductCategoryController::get()->filter('Featured' => 1 'AllowPurchase' => 1)->first();
        if (!$ProductCategory) {
            return null;
        }
    $Product = $ProductCategory->Product()->sort('PublishDate', 'DESC');
   }

Comment: Does anyone have any ideas I could try,please? I can't find any other sources that is helpful to try solve getting the latest products onto my custom template in in my silverstripe themes/app directory. Do I need to include a line in the yml file?

Comment: With the following:

public function FeaturedProducts()
 {
  $Product = \SilverShop\Model\Product\OrderItem::get()->filter(['Featured' => 1, 'AllowPurchase' => 1])->First();
  $controller = \silvershop\core\Page\ProductCategoryController::create();
    
  $ProductCategory = $Product->ProductCategory()->sort('PublishDate', 'DESC');

        return $Product;
 }

Comment: I get this error message:

[Emergency] Uncaught SilverStripe\ORM\Connect\DatabaseException: Couldn't run query: SELECT DISTINCT "SilverShop_OrderAttribute"."ClassName", "SilverShop_OrderAttribute"."LastEdited", "SilverShop_OrderAttribute"."Created", "SilverShop_OrderAttribute"."CalculatedTotal", "SilverShop_OrderAttribute"."OrderID", "SilverShop_OrderItem"."Quantity", "SilverShop_OrderItem"."UnitPrice", "SilverShop_Product_OrderItem"."ProductVersion",

Comment: "SilverShop_Product_OrderItem"."ProductID", "SilverShop_OrderAttribute"."ID", CASE WHEN "SilverShop_OrderAttribute"."ClassName" IS NOT NULL THEN "SilverShop_OrderAttribute"."ClassName" ELSE 'SilverShop\\Model\\OrderAttribute' END AS "RecordClassName" FROM "SilverShop_OrderAttribute" LEFT JOIN "SilverShop_OrderItem" ON "SilverShop_OrderItem"."ID" = "SilverShop_OrderAttribute"."ID" LEFT JOIN "SilverShop_Product_OrderItem" ON "SilverShop_Product_OrderItem"."ID" = "SilverShop_OrderAttribute"."ID" WHERE ("Featured" = ?) AND ("AllowPurchase" = ?) AND ("SilverShop_OrderAttribute"."Clas

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a comma in your array:

```
function FeaturedProducts()
    {
        return Product::get()->filter(array(
            'Featured' => 1,
            'AllowPurchase' => 1
       ));
   }
```

Also make sure you are using the Product class

```
use SilverShop\Page\Product;
```

And in your template:

```
<% if $FeaturedProducts %>

                        <% loop $FeaturedProducts %>
                                $Title
                        <% end_loop %>


            <% end_if %>
```